# Community Default Login Page

Tags: community, force.com, customer-community

I have created a community with all the default pages (login, logout etc.).
But my login page is not showing up. Below is my community URL -

https://commsbx-i3vision.cs43.force.com/SupportCommunity

What am I missing?
Below is my log in controller -

```
global with sharing class CommunitiesLoginController {
global CommunitiesLoginController () {}

// Code we will invoke on page load.
global PageReference forwardToAuthPage() {
    String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
    String displayType = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('display');
    return Network.forwardToAuthPage(startUrl, displayType);
}
  }
```

Comment: Have you edited your log-in controller?

Comment: I updated my question with log in controller. haven't edited it

Comment: I resolved this. The problem was with the CommunityLandingPage. It was showing as modified. I reverted the changes and it started working.
Thanks everyone for all the inputs!

Answer (score 1):

In your site settings you will need to specify default Active page as the login page .

[image]

Comment: Hello Mohith, sorry for this silly question but I am not able to find these settings. Where are these located?

Comment: Set Up > Sites > Click on the Site Label (Note that Label is not Hyperlinked)

Comment: Salesforce Help Page for setting the active site home page for sites. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_creating_and_editing_sites.htm&language=en_US

Comment: I don't see any sites here to click on. Any why do I need a public site for this?

Comment: @ManeeshGupta just search Communities> All communitites> then manage communities and Admin > Pages and then click on Go to Force.com you will find this option.

Comment: It did not work

Answer (score 0):

https://commsbx-i3vision.cs43.force.com/SupportCommunity/login

Try this link you should be able to login it. I tried I can see username and password screen.

Comment: Yes. I already did that but why the default settings are not working?

Comment: If you see your page in the page title it says Site Login. I think you have overridden the default login page with your VF page.

Comment: In the manage communities section, click on Administration check what is your Login page.

Comment: The login page is set to Default

Comment: If its urgent then you can edit the controller and edit the controller and navigate the user to /login page.